# Retrieving number of rows inserted with executeBatch()

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I'm  currently implementing a batch insertion of data into mysql.
I used `INSERT IGNORE` however when i loop through the `int[]` that i received, even rows that are "IGNORED" returns the value `1` but i need to keep track of the number of actual records being inserted.

```
    insert ignore into demographics (mac_address,name,password,email,gender) values(?,?,?,?,?)
```

Comment: I am unable to recreate your issue using mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar. The `int[]` returned by `.executeBatch()` contains `1` for the successful inserts and `0` for the unsuccessful ones. I have pasted my test code [here](http://pastebin.com/FP2UqMir) in case you might find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

executeBatchResults = ps.executeBatch(); // executeBatch() returns int[] where each elements represents number of rows updated per executeBatch() call